# A simple potentiometer problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

The question is given in the pic attached. [image]

Why should there be a change in the balancing length when the keys are closed for resistances $R$ and $X$ one by one? Shouldn't the potential between $A$ and the jockey and $C$ and $D$ be same in both the cases resulting in the same balancing lengths?

Comment: Gee, I think that you're right. Regardless of the value of the resistor placed between C and D, the voltage drop from C to D will always be just the voltage of the lower battery. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how this circuit can be used to measure the resistance of X.

Comment: This is a tricky question.

Comment: Offhand, the circuit appears to be flawed to me. It seems that one way of correcting it would be to substitute a constant-current source for the lower battery. That way, the voltage from C to D would depend on the value of the resistor between those two points. Another option would be to keep the lower battery but to insert an additional resistor between the battery's negative terminal and the current meter "G". That would be another way of making the voltage drop C to D depend on the value of the resistor between points C and D.

Comment: I think that you need to assume that the cell $\mathcal E$  has a constant internal resistance as well as a constant emf.

Comment: @Farcher - That would be a way out of the apparent problem with the circuit. But in reality it would appear to still be a poorly designed circuit because relying on the (unknown) internal resistance of a battery remaining constant is probably a poor assumption, especially in a world where precision, inexpensive 1% resistors are widespread and readily available.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I agree but the OP requested an answer.

Comment: @Farcher - I think that my answer is that the people who wrote the question probably goofed.   :-)

Comment: I remember that the book "The Art of Electronics" had several 'Bad Circuits' sections.  I think this one qualifies for that title.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Your assumption that the lower battery provides a constant current is correct. In the solution, the balancing length is obtained by assuming E to provide a constant current and then finding the potential drop for each resistor.

Comment: @ElShan - Well, the problem is that the question that you showed above doesn't say anything about the lower battery acting as a constant current source. There is nothing in the text of the question that suggests that it is a constant current source, and the symbology in the circuit schematic indicates that it is simply a standard constant voltage source battery with voltage E. In fact, the question describes the battery as a "given cell of emf E".  That's not a constant current source. This appears to be a poorly phrased circuit question.

Comment: @SamuelWeir That's true and the funny thing is that the question is not from a general textbook. The question is from the Physics textbook for 12th grade published by NCERT which is an autonomous organization of the Government of India. NCERT books are considered as the godmother to all the other school level textbooks. I wonder why there hasn't been any correction in the question through all these years.